# Is there a way to make all windows from one application come to the foreground at once?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

Is there some way to foreground all open windows of a single application at once? For example, suppose I open a single Word document. Then suppose I open two separate File Explorer windows and arrange them how I like. Then I go back to Word, which is maximized. Is there a way to now make both of the File Explorer windows come to the foreground in one step? As if, in effect, I had Alt+Tabbed to one and then to the other.

Because the icons on the task bar group open windows from the same application, it **feels** like there should be some way to do this, but maybe there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

### Shift-Right Click

...On the grouped item in the taskbar.  Then select Restore All Windows.

[image: Example image of Shift-Right-Clicking a grouped item on the taskbar]

It appears there is no strictly-keyboard shortcut capable of doing what you're looking for.

While the shown menu can be operated by letters ("R" will Restore all windows), the menu can only be accessed by using the mouse.  While the group can be highlighted (Windows + #, where # is 0-9, referencing the position of the icon on the taskbar), none of its related shortcuts will restore all of the windows for that program.

Comment: Hey, I didn't know about that menu! Restore all windows does look like what I want. But here's something weird: in your example Restore all windows is grayed out. It's also grayed out for me! And I can't seem to find a situation in which it's not grayed out. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've gotten, so far, to what I want is that if I Control+click on the icon on taskbar, it will open each window from the group in turn with each successive click.

Comment: Your example of a perfect solution is "As if, in effect, I had Alt+Tabbed to one and then to the other."  How does this answer not fit the solution you're looking for?

Comment: Because having to do multiple Control-clicks is only a bit better than having to do multiple Alt-Tabs.